# Python subprocess using Idle

Tags: python, subprocess

I am new to python scripting. I am trying to run subprocess methods on Python Idle and getting these errors:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output("ls")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\ramakrishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
  **kwargs).stdout
File "C:\Users\ramakrishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
  with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
File "C:\Users\ramakrishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
  restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\ramakrishna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
  startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help me out to resolve this error.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are running windows. Windows has no "ls" command, so you get a `FileNotFoundError` exception. I am not familiar with windows and python, but try "dir" instead of "ls", that should work.

Comment: I believe 'dir' is also not a file, so I expect 'shell=True' option will be needed.

Comment: Yes, shell=True works fine with 'dir'. Can you please suggest me any materials to get going with os related calls? Please let me know!